# Example of an affine space that is not euclidean

Tags: euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

Wikipedia says that Euclidean space is affine (obvious), but that not all affine spaces are Euclidean.

I understand that Euclidean space has extra structure defined on it, namely metrics of distance and angles.

**However, are there actual examples of affine spaces that are not Euclidean?**

ps. I am not talking about the vector space $R^d$, but about the manifold $E^d$, which is a metric affine space, but not a vector space, though it can be charted by the cartesian coordinates in $R^d$.

Comment: How about the [Moulton plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulton_plane)?

Comment: Indeed. Wow, ok  that is very weird. I'm having a hard time seeing why this is affine, but I'll look at it some more. Is there a more intuitive example?

Comment: It's probably possible to construct a "more intuitive" example, but this was the simplest example for which I could find a Wiki page with an image on it.

Answer (score 4):

A space with a [Minkowski geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Geometry) is an affine space with a non euclidean geometry. In such a geometry the notion of orthogonality is defined using an ''inner product'' that is not positive defined and we have not the usual rotations but [hyperbolic rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_mapping#Relativistic_spacetime).  This is the geometry of the relativity theory.

Answer (score 0):

An euclidean space is an affine space which contain $0$.

So for instance the line of equation $y=1$ in the plane in an affine space, but it is not an euclidean space ($0$ does not belong to this line).

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You are implicitly saying that $E^d =R^d$, but $R^d$ in that sense is technically only the cartesian coordinate system of the manifold $E^d$. $R^d$ is a vector space, but $E^d$ is not. Maybe you think this is nitpicking (or that I am wrong), but it is essential to my question, because otherwise indeed I would have thought of that example.